# temporary column name in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to give custom but temporary names (i.e., I dont want to alter the data.table using ":=") to the columns of a data.table after a column expression like mean. I have looked at some examples which use eval function but I want to do this in a single line of code. How can we do it? thank you!

I have this data

```
steps.dt = data.table(steps=rep(0:2, each=3), 
date=as.factor(rep(c("10/2/2012", "10/3/2012", "10/4/2012"), each = 3)), interval = as.factor(rep(c(0,5,10), each = 3)))

steps.dt

   steps      date interval
1:     0 10/2/2012        0
2:     0 10/2/2012        0
3:     0 10/2/2012        0
4:     1 10/3/2012        5
5:     1 10/3/2012        5
6:     1 10/3/2012        5
7:     2 10/4/2012       10
8:     2 10/4/2012       10
9:     2 10/4/2012       10
```

Now when I calculate means only to get a sense of the data and not modify it

```
steps.dt[,mean(steps), by = interval]
   interval V1
1:        0  0
2:        5  1
3:       10  2
```

I get the result under a column named "V1". I want to give it a custom name like "steps.mean" without altering the data table using ":=" in the column expression.

Comment: Name the column inside the `J` expression: `steps.dt[, .(steps.mean = mean(steps)), by = interval]`

Comment: thank you @SymbolixAU! I didn't know . could be used like this in the J expr. Pls. reply and I will accept...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To name the column in a calculation you just need to set the name in the `J` expression

```
steps.dt[, .(steps.mean = mean(steps)), by = interval]
```

And to only display the mean column, you can chain an expression onto the end to only show the column of interest

```
steps.dt[, .(steps.mean = mean(steps)), by = interval][, .(steps.mean)]
## or, if you only want a vector of values returned, don't use the .()
# steps.dt[, .(steps.mean = mean(steps)), by = interval][, steps.mean]
```

Comment: on a related note - how can we display only the steps.mean col without the interval? I want to pass this to a hist function so I just want the means...

Comment: You probably want `[['steps.mean']]` (to access the values, rather than a single-column data.table.)

Answer (score -3):

We can do this with `base R`

```
aggregate(steps~interval, steps.dt, mean)
```